# JavaScript RegEx match all characters from set except some

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to test whether a string contains only punctuation symbols except one character symbol say hypen (-)

1. '??...' -> true
2. '.!sf' -> false
3. '..-??' -> false

I use library XRegEx library that allows to match for example punctuation with p{P} but I need to exclude some characters from this match.

I use following pattern:

```
new XRegExp("^\\p{P}+$")
```

How can I except hypen symbol from "-" this match?

N.B. Original question was about "leters":
I need to test whether a string contains letters except one character say letter "m"

Comment: @WHITECOLOR you do understand your question specifically states that you need to test a string for letters except 'm', and suddenly that's not your question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I would be more common to explain with letters example.

Comment: Please make it clearer, help us to help you

Comment: I will create the other question and remove this one after

Comment: I'm still not understanding why the already provided solutions don't answer the question.  You give an example of wanting to exclude 'm' from the match...that seems to be what they're giving you.  Explain where they're missing the mark, and you'll have better luck getting what you want.

Comment: NO DONT, YOU CANT DELETE THIS BECAUSE IT HAS ANSWERS! STOP! (hammertime (js room will get it))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[a-ln-z]+$/.test('abcfx')
// true
/^[a-ln-z]+$/.test('abcfx12.!')
// false
/^[a-ln-z]+$/.test('abcmfx')
// false
```

Using positive lookahead:

```
/^(?=[^m]+$)[a-z]+$/.test('abcfx')
// true
/^(?=[^m]+$)[a-z]+$/.test('abcfx12.!')
// false
/^(?=[^m]+$)[a-z]+$/.test('abcmfx')
// false
```

Comment: Hm, thanks, but I need another way. Because I my case I it not leters

Comment: @WHITECOLOR, `not letters`? What does it mean?

Comment: @falsetru you understood that??

Comment: I use library XRegEx that allows to match for example punctuations p{P} but I need to exclude some characters from this match.

Comment: @WHITECOLOR, I updated the answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: @falsetru: the question's been changed _again_.

Comment: @falsetru You *earned* that rep.  Well done.

Comment: Downvoter: How can I improve the answer?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is probably this regex, which accepts ranges from `a` to `l` and from `n` to `z`

```
^[a-ln-z]+$
```